# post submit button value with serialize function for php validation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to post button value with serialize() function. problem is serialize() will not post button values. I have in my form SAVE, UPDATE, and DELETE buttons.Then PHP must know which button click to particular operation. I can get button value with click function , but how it to pass to the PHP page with Ajax. My codes are below ,also get from stackoverflow.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#btnUpdate").click(function() {

          alert($(this).attr("value"));

            /* attach a submit handler to the form */
                $("#form1").submit(function(event) {

                /* stop form from submitting normally */
                event.preventDefault();

                /*clear result div*/
               $("#result").html('');

                /* get some values from elements on the page: */
               var values = $(this).serialize();

              /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
                $.ajax({
                  url: "form.php",
                  type: "post",
                  data: values,
                  success: function(data){
                      alert("success");
                              alert(data);
                       $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
                  },
                  error:function(){
                  alert("failure");
                  $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                    }   
            }); 
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax post serialize() does not include button name and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866459/ajax-post-serialize-does-not-include-button-name-and-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get button value, put it right where you have the alert:

```
var buttonvalue = $(this).val();
```

and then you can append it to the serialized data by doing this:

```
var values = $('#form1').serialize();
values = values + '&button='+buttonvalue;
```

The '&button=' is what it will be called when you are testing to see which button was used.

Comment: No problem. Please accept as the answer when you can if you don't mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) states that `No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.`.

Anyway, you could do it by appending the button name and value to `serialize()` output like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866762/72746).

Answer (score 0):

i think you would like to try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#btnUpdate").click(function() {


            /* attach a submit handler to the form */
                $("#form1").submit(function(event) {

                /* stop form from submitting normally */
                event.preventDefault();

                /*clear result div*/
               $("#result").html('');

                /* get some values from elements on the page: */
               var values = $(this).serialize();

              /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
                $.ajax({
                  url: "form.php",
                  type: "post",
                  data: values + '&' + 'button=' $(this).attr('value'),
                  success: function(data){
                      alert("success");
                              alert(data);
                       $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
                  },
                  error:function(){
                  alert("failure");
                  $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                    }   
            }); 
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: I think same rncrtr's method