# Unable to get value of submit button in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need some help getting the value of a submit button. The code below fires off my controller function, but I am unable to get the value of the 'Invite' button. var_dump states 'bool(false)' and a 0 for Educator_Id is inserted into my final query to the database.

Thanks for any help you can give!

My submit button:

```
<?php foreach($educators as $educator): ?>
    <button type="submit" id="Invite" name="Invite" value="<?php echo $educator->Educator_Id; ?>">Invite</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My jQuery function:

```
$("#Invite").click(function() {
    var form_data = $('#validation-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/send_invite'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data
    });

    return false;
})
```

My controller:

```
function send_invite() {
    $email = $this->input->post('Educator_Email');
    $Opportunity_Id = $this->input->post('Opportunity_Id');
    $Educator_Id = $this->input->post('Invite');
    $Class_Numbers = $this->input->post('Class_Numbers');

    foreach($Class_Numbers as $Class_Number):
        $this->ion_auth_model->update_class_educator($Opportunity_Id, $Class_Number, $Educator_Id);
    endforeach;
}
```

My model:

```
function update_class_educator($Opportunity_Id, $Educator_Class, $Educator_Id) {
    $Class = array(
        'Educator_Id' => $Educator_Id
    );

    $this->db->where('Opportunity_Id', $Opportunity_Id);
    $this->db->where('Class_Number', $Educator_Class);
    $this->db->update('Classes', $Class);
}
```

Comment: You couldn't narrow it down to either the PHP or JavaScript? That should be easy enough to do.

Comment: @JohnConde Seems to be a PHP issue to me.

Comment: according to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866762/689579 - jquery `.serialize()` does not encode buttons.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ says "Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button."

Comment: do a `console.debug` of `form_data`

Comment: From reading the docs, you could likely include the selector from the clicked button and it would include it. so `$('#validation-form, #Invite').serialize();`. Only other thing I would suggest is give each button a unique id because they are supposed to be unique.

Comment: `id`s should be unique, but since you are creating these in a loop -> `foreach($educators as $educator):` you will end up with `n` `id="Invite"`, so when using `$("#Invite").click(function(){` how will jquery know which button value you want to include?

Comment: Turn the buttons into checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try to passing the value to a hidden input

JavaScript:

```
$("#Invite").live("click", function(){
  var this_value = $(this).val();
  $("input[name='InviteValue']").val(this_value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using button use input like this :

```
<?php 
  $count = 0;
  foreach($educators as $educator): ?>
     <input type="submit" id="Invite_$count" class="invite" name="Invite" data-value="<?php echo $educator->Educator_Id; ?>" value="Invite"/>
<?php
  $count++;
  endforeach; ?>
```

And in jquery you can use :

```
$(".invite").click(function() {
    var submit_data = $(this).data('value');
    var form_data = $('#validation-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/send_invite'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data + "&submit_data=" + submit_data
    });

    return false;
})
```

In Controller:

```
function send_invite() {
    $email = $this->input->post('Educator_Email');
    $Opportunity_Id = $this->input->post('Opportunity_Id');
    $Educator_Id = $this->input->post('submit_data');
    $Class_Numbers = $this->input->post('Class_Numbers');

    foreach($Class_Numbers as $Class_Number):
        $this->ion_auth_model->update_class_educator($Opportunity_Id, $Class_Number, $Educator_Id);
    endforeach;
}
```

Try it. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still getting the same result though.

Comment: Oh sorry, there was a mistake in my solution. I didnot noticed the for loop and used the same "id" in the loop. I am correcting it by adding a class and then it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the PHP:

```
 <?php
    foreach($educators as $educator){ 
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='invite[]' value='".$educator->Educator_Id."'>".$educator."<br/>";
    } 
    echo "<input type='submit' value="Invite"/>";
```

It will render a checkbox for each educator and a SINGLE submit button. Then, in your JS:

```
$("#invite").click(function() {
var form_data = $('#validation-form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/send_invite'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(){
        // Do something here if succeded
    }
});

return false;
```

});

This way it only sends checked checkboxes to the server, so you can handle who is selected in your controller from there.

```
$Educator_Id = $this->input->post("invite[]");
```

instead of

```
$Educator_Id = $this->input->post('Invite');
```

I think that should work... Your final goal is a little unclear to me, but your logic is what's off in this case, and this should help clear things up.

Cheers!