# My $.post function doesn't return any data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to Php and Ajax, and I've been banging my head over this problem. I'm trying to get my simple form to update with ajax using the `$.post` shorthand function, but my script just doesn't return anything. I've tried with `$.ajax` as well, and used different data types like json objects, json variable, `serialize()` .. etc.

---

HTML

```
    <section class="contact" id="contact">



  <h2>Do you have a project in mind? Let's discuss it</h2>

    <div id="form-messages">

    </div>


   <form action="" method="post" id="contact-form">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-4"><label for="name">Your name</label></div>
            <div class="col span-3-of-4"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name ..."></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-4"><label for="email">Your email</label></div>
            <div class="col span-3-of-4"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email ..."></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-4"><label for="message">Your message</label></div>
            <div class="col span-3-of-4"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type in your message ..."></textarea></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4"></div>
            <div class="col span-3-of-4"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send your message"></div>

        </div>
    </form>




</section>
```

PHP

```
<?php           

$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$error="";
$result="";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if (!$name) {
    $error="<br />Please enter your name";
}
if (!$email) {
    $error.="<br />Please enter your email address";
}
if (!$message) {
    $error.="<br />Please enter a message";
}

if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    }                       
if ($error) {
    $result='<div class="error-message"><p id="alert"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</p></div>';
} else {
    if (mail("abderrahim.gadmy@gmail.com", "Gadmy Visions: Someone sent you a message!", 
    "Name: ". $_POST['name']."
    Email: ".$_POST['email']."
    Comment: ".$_POST['message'])) {
        $result='<div class="success-message"><p id="alert"><strong>Thank you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch</p></div>';
    } else {                                                 
        $result='<div class="error-message"><p id="alert">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</p></div>';
    }
}

 echo $result;
}

?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#contact-form').on('submit',function(event){



    $.post('contact.php',$('form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#form-messages').html(data);        
    });

    //Prevent refresh
    event.preventDefault();      

    });

});
```

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST)` in your php file and check if you're actually posting data. Also: What does your browsers console / network tools say? Is the requets happening? Is the data posted?

Comment: Obviously, the function executes, and when I log the result to console, it just gives an empty string.

Comment: Your php file only outputs something if `$_POST["submit"]` is set, hence the idea to var_dump it's contents since it seems to not execute. Also: log `$('form').serialize()` to the JS console for further debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax post serialize() does not include button name and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866459/ajax-post-serialize-does-not-include-button-name-and-value)

Comment: After putting in this:

        $('#contact-form').on('submit',function(event){
        
            
            console.log($('form').serialize());
            event.preventDefault(); 

I did get the form inputs on the console

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking whether the form can be submitted by using

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  instead of using isset($_POST["submit"])) .

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:

jQuery serialize() does not serialize buttons (since it doesn't know which button was used to submit the form). See: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866459/ajax-post-serialize-does-not-include-button-name-and-value) aswell as the [jQuery serialize documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

Since your PHP-File only generates output if `$_POST["submit"]` is set (which isn't the case since it's not serialized along with the rest of the form) nothing is actually returned.

Either use a different condition in your php file to check if the form was actually POSTed successfully or manually append the submit button to the serialized data.