# Posting the name of the submit field

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have a form with one input field and submit button. I know the name of the button can be submitted but for some reason, it isn't being posted to the server.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).serialize());
      return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div class="a">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="projectName" type="text">
</div>
<div class="b">
  <input name="newProject" value="Save Project" type="submit"></div> 
</form>
```

output: `projectName=abc`
Expected output: `projectName=abc`, `newProject=Save Project`

Why is the "newProject" name not being sent to the server?

Comment: [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/): _"Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. **No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button**."_

Comment: You could always use a hidden input with a value if you want to do it that way.

Comment: So the only way is to use hidden input or query for the value before posting?

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866459/ajax-post-serialize-does-not-include-button-name-and-value?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add data on top:

```
var value = $("[name='newProject']").val();
var data = $(this).serializeArray();
data.push({submit: value});
```

Comment: Looks like I have to do it this way. Thanks