# Symfony 3 - The CSRF token is invalid ONLY when submitting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

After looking around I could not find a solution to this. I am getting error below ONLY when submitting thru Ajax. Meaning that I have beforehand submitted the form in the regular Symfony fashion without an issue.

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

What works:

- the regular form submission, ie, without Ajax
- with Ajax I checked that $_POST is correctly populated, including the CSFR token, just before the submission on the controller side, as follows:

> $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName('user')));

As requested, see below output of

> var_dump($request->request->get($form->getName('user')));

```
array(8) { 
["name"]=> string(9) "fafdffafa" 
["avatar"]=> string(9) "dfafffafa" 
["cityId"]=> string(1) "6" 
["phone"]=> string(14) "33434343434344" 
["email"]=> array(2) { 
      ["first"]=> string(22) "myemail@gmail.com" 
      ["second"]=> string(22) "myemail@gmail.com" } 
["plainPassword"]=> array(2) { 
      ["first"]=> string(8) "senha444" 
      ["second"]=> string(8) "senha444" } 
["blogSubs"]=> string(1) "1" 
["_token"]=> string(43) "hLhyoRxVYmJ_FWK0FqXmiiEYZMZ77fDAWvxCZMXCtxw" }
```

Just to confirm that **if I just comment out the javascript below** the submission will work and the entity will be persisted.

This is the same var_dump, this time for when things work.

```
array(9) { 
["name"]=> string(12) "dfdfdfdfafaf" 
["avatar"]=> string(13) "dfdfdfdafdafa" 
["cityId"]=> string(1) "8" 
["phone"]=> string(16) "3343434343343343" 
["email"]=> array(2) { 
    ["first"]=> string(22) "myemail@gmail.com" 
    ["second"]=> string(22) "myemail@gmail.com" }
["plainPassword"]=> array(2) { 
    ["first"]=> string(8) "senha444" 
    ["second"]=> string(8) "senha444" } 
["blogSubs"]=> string(1) "1" 
["save"]=> string(0) "" 
["_token"]=> string(43) "hLhyoRxVYmJ_FWK0FqXmiiEYZMZ77fDAWvxCZMXCtxw" }
```

This is the submit button generated by Symfony, but not captured by js serialization.

```
<button type="submit" id="user_save" name="user[save]" class="btn-default btn">Créer mon compte</button>
```

The form ( I am skipping the form $builder as it seems unnecessary )

app/Resources/views/common/register.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'id': 'signup_form' }}) }}
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.avatar) }}
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="info_avatar">
            <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
        </span>       
    </div>
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.cityId) }}
    </div>
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.phone) }}           
    </div>
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    </div>
    <div class="contact input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        {{ form_widget(form.blogSubs) }}
    </div>
    <div class="contact form-group ">
        {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The javascript on the same file:

```
<script>
    $('body').on('submit','#signup_form',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var str = $("#signup_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/inscription",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data: str,
            success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
            }   
        });
    });
  </script>
```

And the controller ( the getErrorMessages() method was found on SO.)

/src/UsedBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

```
namespace UsedBundle\Controller;

use UsedBundle\Form\UserType;
use UsedBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/inscription", name="inscription")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName('user')));
        if(!$form->isValid()){ 
            $errors = $this->getErrorMessages($form);
            var_dump($errors);
        }
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $email = $user->getEmail();
            $user->setUserKey( $email );
            $user->setUserKeyTime();
            $user->setDateReg();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('used');
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'));
        }
    }else{
        return $this->render(
            'common/register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );           
    }
}

protected function getErrorMessages($form) 
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
} 
}
```

Comment: Does `$("#signup_form").serialize();` have the CSRF token ?

Comment: `var_dump($request->request->get($form->getName('user')));` ?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, yes, as you can see I have a var_dump($_POST) just before submission on the controller to verify that.

Comment: @MaxP. fresh from the oven:array(8) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "fafdffafa"
  ["avatar"]=>
  string(9) "dfafffafa"
  ["cityId"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(14) "33434343434344"
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(22) "myemail@gmail.com"
    ["second"]=>
    string(22) "myemail@gmail.com"
  }
  ["plainPassword"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(8) "senha444"
    ["second"]=>
    string(8) "senha444"
  }
  ["blogSubs"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["_token"]=>
  string(43) "hLhyoRxVYmJ_FWK0FqXmiiEYZMZ77fDAWvxCZMXCtxw"
}

Comment: @Bernard, you may wish to format it and post it in your question as an update, as it looks jumbled-up in the comment

Comment: @Dennis, done as requested, thanks.

Comment: @MaxP.,@Dennis  I believe I found what the issue might be. As said, this works correctly without Ajax. I just tried the var_dump suggested by Max P without Ajax, ie, when things work. The issue seems to be that the javascript serialization does not capture the submit button. I will post on the question how the var_dump looks when it works. That being said, I do not know why js does not get that, and it is clear that Symfony requires it.

Comment: mm silly question perhaps but does the submit button have a `name` attribute?

Comment: @Dennis. Yes, I just added the code for the button to my question. It's the plain widget generated by Symfony by {{ form_widget(form.save) }}

Comment: mmm I know there have been issues in the past as far as using `<button>` tag, to where `<input type="button" />` worked better.  I think with modern browsers and modern AJAX libraries this is no longer an issue ... but if you change the Submit `<button>` to be an `<input>` field, I wonder if it will help... but it looks like jQuery's `serialize()` may indeed be skipping this, i.e. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866459/ajax-post-serialize-does-not-include-button-name-and-value/9866762

Comment: in other words, you may want to use the submit button for event control only, and move any value that you are getting from the submit button into the `<input>` (or other non-button/non-control) form element.

Comment: Or fake it to where button's data is submitted to make Symfony happy.

Comment: @Dennis, Well, the button is generated by Symfony  This is the code on the $builder ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Créer mon compte'))

Comment: @Dennis  The documentation is very specific about being a button as well [link] (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html). Not sure how I can circumvent that. If you do, please answer it.

Comment: @BernardA the Ajax call uses the  `/inscription` location and is not aware of environments. If you are using the standard Symfony edition, you may have a problem here with generating the form in `dev` environment and the ajax call going to `prod` environment. Can you check if that is the case?

Comment: @lordrhodos, you are absolutely right. It does work if I submit the form from /inscription and not from /app_dev.php/inscription. Now, what's the solution? I hope I do not have to code one thing for dev and then have to log somewhere and change all the particulars before moving to prod.

Comment: It depends a little bit how you want to generate the routes in front end. I see at least two options here. Disable csrf in dev environment or use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) to generate routes in frontend.

Comment: @lordrhodos, I prefer disabling CSRF. It seems cleaner and easier to reset for prod. I just tried and it works, so put it up as an answer and I will accept it, thanks. Also, I do not fancy getting into still another bundle, at least not for now.

Comment: it is hacky but my suggestion was along the line of .. add a hidden `<input>` element to compensate for `serialize` not serializing submit control.  It looks like Symfony depends on the control to send CSRF, which they probably shouldn't...

Comment: @BernardA I will put up the answer once I am back home tomorrow and have access to a decent computer and not just a tablet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the cause of your issue is related to different environments. If you are using the standard Symfony project with the `app_dev.php` frontend controller your forms will be rendered with a valid csrf token for the `dev` environment. Your javascript code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/inscription",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data: str,
    success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
    }   
});
```

is not aware of the Symfony environment so the url `/location` points to the `prod` environment, resulting in the error message that the CSRF token is not valid.

To solve this issue you can either make your frontend code aware of the Symfony routing, e.g. by using the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle). Or you can disable the CSRF protection for the `dev` environment:

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
framework:
    csrf_protection: false
```